# Для чего здесь нужен массив "у"?

Tags: javascript

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<!-- 
var a = new Array(); //...?
var x = new Array(),
    y = new Array();
var tn, tk, dt; //...?
var v0n, v0k, dv0; //...?
var q; //...?
var v0 //...?
function clear_table() {
    //зачищаем таблицу
    for (var i = tbl.rows.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) tbl.deleteRow(i);
}

//функция заполняет таблицу с идентификатором id=tbl (см. ниже) результатами расчетов
function fill_in_table(
caption, //заголовок таблицы
x, //х-значения - в шапку таблицы
y, //y-значения, а именно
//y[i][0], ..., y[i][n] - y-значения для i-ой строки таблицы
p //p[i] - левая колонка таблицы
) {
    clear_table();
    //установим заголовок таблицы
    var tblCaption = tbl.createCaption();
    tblCaption.innerHTML = caption;
    tblCaption.style.fontWeight = "bold";
    //первая строка - шапка таблицы
    var row = tbl.insertRow(); //создали строку
    row.style.background = "yellow"; //выделили ее цветом
    var cell = row.insertCell(); //создали первую клетку в строке
    cell.style.textAlign = "center"; //выровняли ее содержимое по центру
    cell.innerHTML = 'a&nbsp;&#92;&nbsp;t'; //...?
    //создали и заполнили оставшиеся клетки
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        cell = row.insertCell();
        cell.style.textAlign = "center";
        cell.innerHTML = "" + x[i];
    }
    //аналогично заполнили тело таблицы
    for (var i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
        row = tbl.insertRow();
        cell = row.insertCell();
        cell.style.textAlign = "center";
        cell.style.background = "yellow";
        cell.innerHTML = "" + p[i];
        for (var j = 0; j < x.length; j++) {
            cell = row.insertCell();
            cell.style.textAlign = "center";
            cell.innerHTML = "" + Math.round(y[i][j] * 100) / 100; //округлили до 2-х знаков
        }
    }
}

//здесь собственно расчет
function calc(v0) //...?
{
    //формируем массив x, содержащий различные значения параметра p3
    var j = 0;
    for (var t = tn; t <= tk + dt / 2; t = t + dt) {
        x[j] = t;
        j++;
    } //...?
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) //перебираем все значения параметра p2 ...?
    {
        var s = new Array(); //этот массив будет содержать вычисляемые по формуле значения ...?
        // для различных значений параметра p3
        // и фиксированного значения параметра p2[i]
        for (j = 0; j < x.length; j++) {
            //внимание!!! далее находится расчетная формула
            //вместо имени вашего параметра p3 должно быть x[j]
            s[j] = v0 * x[j] + a[i] * x[j] * x[j] * q / 2; //...?
        }
        y[i] = s; //...?
    }

    //формируем таблицу
    fill_in_table("Зависимость расстояния S от ускорения a и времени t (v0=" + v0 + ")", x, y, a); //...?
}

//отклик на нажатие кнопки "далее"
function more() {
    if (v0 > v0k + dv0 / 2) return; //...?
    calc(v0); //...?
    v0 += dv0; //...?
}

//отклик на нажатие кнопки "график"
function graph() {
    //формируем объект, который будет содержать все
    //необходимые данные для прорисовки графиков и
    //который будет передан странице, выполняющей прорисовку
    var args = new Object(); //создали объект
    args.a = a; //...?
    args.v0 = v0 - dv0; //...?
    args.x = x; //абсцисссы
    args.y = y; //y[i][0]...y[i][n] - ординаты для i-ой кривой
    //показали графики
    showModalDialog("graph00.html", args, "center:yes;help:no;resizable:yes;scroll:no;status:no;");
}

function init() {
    a = window.dialogArguments.a; //...?
    tn = window.dialogArguments.tn;
    tk = window.dialogArguments.tk; //...?
    dt = window.dialogArguments.dt; //...?
    v0n = window.dialogArguments.v0n;
    v0k = window.dialogArguments.v0k; //...?
    dv0 = window.dialogArguments.dv0; //...?
    q = window.dialogArguments.q; //...?
    v0 = v0n;
    calc(v0);
    v0 += dv0; //...?
}
-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А разве этот коментарий не объясняет?

```
y,          //y-значения, а именно
            //y[i][0], ..., y[i][n] - y-значения для i-ой строки таблицы
```

Comment: А можно как нибудь подробнее объяснить?просто я не так давно с JavaScript знаком.